# Wordpress Category Echo in Loop always echos the categories of the first post on the Page (Blog-Roll)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog roll in wordpress and want each post on the page to echo the categories it belongs to.

The Code is as follows:

```
<?php else: ?>
<footer class="loop">
    <?php if(has_category()): ?>
    <div class="categories">

        <?php the_category(', '); ?>
    </div>

    <span class="sep"></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( ! has_post_format('link')): ?>
    <div class="comments_count">
        <a href="<?php echo get_comments_link(); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d Comment', '%d Comments', $commennts_count), $commennts_count); ?></a>
    </div>

    <span class="sep"></span>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="read_more">
        <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>"><?php has_post_format('link') ? _e('Go to link', TD) : _e('Read More', TD); ?></a>
    </div>
</footer>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The Problem I have is, it always outputs the categories of the first post on that page for every post.

I tried doing stuff like this and passing the post ID but it doesnt seem to work any better:

```
 <?php
 global $post;
 $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
 $cat_link = get_category_link($categories[0]->cat_ID);
 echo '<a href="'.$cat_link.'">'.$categories[0]->cat_name.'</a>' 
 ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Entire Code as requested:

```
    <?php
/**
 *  Post Item 1
 *  
 *  Laborator.co
 *  www.laborator.co 
 */

global $post, $blog_columns, $text_position;

setup_postdata($post);

$id                     = get_the_ID();
$post_thumbnails_show   = get_data('blog_post_thumbnails');
$thumbnails_single_show = get_data('blog_post_thumbnails_single');
$has_thumbnail          = $post_thumbnails_show && has_post_thumbnail();
$commennts_count        = get_comments_number();
$featured_image         = null;

if(is_single())
{
    $featured_image_visibility = $post->featured_image_visibility;

    if($has_thumbnail)
    {
        $has_thumbnail = $thumbnails_single_show;

        if($featured_image_visibility == 'visible')
            $has_thumbnail = true;
    }


    $thumbnail_height = $post->thumbnail_height;


    if($featured_image_visibility == 'hide')
    {
        $has_thumbnail = false;
    }
}
else
{
    $thumbnail_height = intval(get_data('blog_post_thumbnail_height'));
}

if($thumbnail_height)
{
    $def_height = $post->thumbnail_height;
}

if($has_thumbnail)
{
    $featured_image = laborator_show_img($id, $def_width, $def_height, 4);
}

$extra_classes = is_sticky($id) ? ' sticky-post' : '';

$permalink = get_permalink();
$target = '_self';

$gallery_images = null;
$quote_text = null;
$video_info = null;

$content = get_the_content();

# Post Formats
if(has_post_format('link'))
{
    $link = extract_first_link($content);

    if($link)
    {
        $permalink = $link;

        if( ! stristr($permalink, home_url()))
        {
            $target = '_blank';
        }
    }
}
else
if(has_post_format('gallery'))
{
    wp_enqueue_script('laborator_answiper');

    $gallery_images = extract_gallery_images($id, $post);
}
else
if(has_post_format('quote'))
{
    $quote_text = extract_quote_text($content);
}
elseif($post_thumbnails_show && has_post_format('video'))
{
    $video_info = extract_video_link($content);

    if( ! $featured_image)
    {
        $extra_classes .= " video_no_thumbnail";
    }
}

if(has_post_format('audio'))
{
    $audio_shortcode = extract_custom_shortcode($post, 'audio');
}

if(has_post_format('video'))
{
    $video_shortcode = extract_custom_shortcode($post, 'video');
}

if(is_single())
{
    $text_position = get_data('blog_single_post_text_alignment');

    $post_text_position = get_post_meta($id, 'text_alignment', true);

    if(in_array($post_text_position, array('Left', 'Center')))
    {
        $text_position = $post_text_position;
    }
}

if(isset($text_position) && $text_position == 'Left')
{
    $extra_classes .= ' text_left';
}

if($blog_columns == 2)
{
    if( ! isset($class_odd_index))
    {
        $class_odd_index = 1;
    }

    if($class_odd_index % 2 == 0)
    {
        $extra_classes .= ' odd';
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div class="blog_<?php echo $blog_columns; ?>_clear"></div>
        <?php
    }

    $class_odd_index++;
}

?>
<article <?php post_class('blog_post sm_show' . $extra_classes); ?>>

    <?php if(has_post_format('link')): ?>
    <div class="post_icon link"></div>
    <?php elseif(has_post_format('gallery') && count($gallery_images)): ?>
    <div class="post_icon gallery"></div>
    <?php elseif(has_post_format('video')): ?>
    <div class="post_icon video"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <header>

        <?php 
        if(has_post_format('audio') && isset($audio_shortcode)):

            $post_old = $post;
            echo do_shortcode($audio_shortcode);
            $post = $post_old;

        elseif(has_post_format('video') && isset($video_shortcode)):

            $post_old = $post;
            ?>
            <div class="video_container">
            <?php
            echo do_shortcode($video_shortcode);
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            $post = $post_old;

        endif; 
        ?>

        <?php if($has_thumbnail && ! has_post_format('video')): ?>
            <?php
                if(is_single())
                {
                    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($id);
                    $featured_image_permalink = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'original');
                }
            ?>
        <a href="<?php echo is_single() ? $featured_image_permalink[0] : $permalink ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>" class="image"<?php if(is_single()): ?> rel="shadowbox;" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $featured_image; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if(has_post_format('video') && is_array($video_info) && $video_info['type'] != 'unknown'): ?>
        <div class="video">
            <?php 
            if($has_thumbnail && $video_info['type'] != 'unknown')
            {
                $more = '';

                if($video_info['type'] == 'youtube' || $video_info['type'] == 'vimeo')
                {
                    $more = '?autoplay=1';
                }
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $video_info['link'] . $more; ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>" rel="shadowbox[video-gallery];width=850;height=500;player=iframe" class="image">
                    <?php echo $featured_image; ?>
                </a>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                laborator_show_video_frame($video_info); 
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        if( ! empty($gallery_images) && count($gallery_images) > 0 && ( ! $blog_columns || $blog_columns == 1)): 
        ?>
        <div class="post_gallery_nav"></div>

        <div class="post_gallery">
            <?php           
            foreach($gallery_images as $image):

                $guid = $image->guid;
                $thumb = laborator_img($guid, 'post-gallery-thumb');
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $guid; ?>" rel="shadowbox[gallery_<?php echo $id; ?>]" title="<?php echo esc_attr($image->post_title); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" />
                <span></span>
            </a>
            <?php 
                endforeach;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( ! empty($quote_text)): ?>
        <blockquote class="quote">
            <?php echo $quote_text; ?>
        </blockquote>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h1 class="title">
            <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>

        <div class="date">
            <span><?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) {
echo "Last updated on ";
the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
echo ", "; }
else {echo "Posted on "; the_time('F jS, Y');} ?></span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <?php if(is_single()): ?>
        <div class="post_content">
            <?php 

                if( ! is_attachment()):

                    the_content(); 

                    wp_link_pages(array(
                        'before' => '<div class="post_pagination">' . __('Page: ', TD),
                        'after' => '</div>',
                        'pagelink' => '<span class="current">%</span>'
                    ));

                else:

                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>" class="aligncenter" />
                    </a>
                    <?php

                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="excerpt">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_single()): ?>
    <footer class="single">
        <div class="sep_2"></div>

        <div class="post_meta">

            <?php if(has_category()): ?>
            <!-- category -->
            <div class="meta">
                <i class="categories"></i>
                <div>
                    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- author -->
            <?php if( ! get_data('blog_post_author_info') || is_attachment()): ?>
            <div class="meta">
                <i class="author"></i>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php elseif(has_tag()): ?>
            <div class="meta">
                <i class="tags"></i>
                <div class="tags_area">
                    <?php the_tags(''); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
            $blog_social_networks_list = get_data('blog_social_networks_list');

            if(is_array($blog_social_networks_list)):

                foreach($blog_social_networks_list as $sn => $include)
                {
                    if( ! $include)
                    {
                        unset($blog_social_networks_list[$sn]);
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <!-- share -->
            <div class="meta right">
                <i class="share"></i>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="share_post social-share" data-social="<?php echo implode(',', array_keys($blog_social_networks_list)); ?>"><?php _e('Share this post', TD); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </footer>
    <?php else: ?>
    <footer class="loop">

        <?php if(has_category()): ?>
        <div class="categories">
            <?php the_category(', '); ?>
        </div>

        <span class="sep"></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if( ! has_post_format('link')): ?>
        <div class="comments_count">
            <a href="<?php echo get_comments_link(); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d Comment', '%d Comments', $commennts_count), $commennts_count); ?></a>
        </div>

        <span class="sep"></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="read_more">
            <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>"><?php has_post_format('link') ? _e('Go to link', TD) : _e('Read More', TD); ?></a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_single() && get_data('blog_post_author_info') && ! is_attachment()): ?>
    <footer class="author_info_env">
        <div class="sep_3"></div>
        <?php get_template_part('tpls/blog', 'authorinfo'); ?>
    </footer>
    <?php endif; ?>
</article>
<?php
```

Comment: is this inside the loop ? share the full code

Comment: Thanks! I added the entire code of blog-posts.php. The section is almost at the end.